# subset of R dataframe matching two column criteria in 2nd dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm working on a transcriptomics project and I have a data frame with columns for "SampleIDs", "hugo_name", and "Expression". The DF has thousands of rows because of many gene names for each sample. I'm trying to do a QC step using a set of 10 housekeeping genes in which I eliminate all "Sample IDs" for which less than 9/10 of the housekeeping genes are expressed above a cutoff value. Basically, I want to take all genes in DF$hugo_name that match a list of 10 genes and for each gene name, check its expression value to make sure it's above my list of cutoff values.

My data frame with 10 housekeeping genes and lower cutoff expression values:

```
    EHK_list <- c("C1orf43", "CHMP2A", "GPI", "PSMB2", "PSMB4", "RAB7A", "REEP5", "SNRPD3", "VCP", "VPS29")
    EHK_minimum <- data_frame("hugo_name" = EHK_list, "expression" = c(2.3697, 3.4964, 2.0620, 2.1240, 4.3081, 8.3988, 1.4969, -0.0066, 2.5436, 5.2886))
      show(EHK_minimum)
     <chr>          <dbl>
     1 C1orf43       2.37  
     2 CHMP2A        3.50  
     3 GPI           2.06  
     4 PSMB2         2.12  
     5 PSMB4         4.31  
     6 RAB7A         8.40  
     7 REEP5         1.50  
     8 SNRPD3       -0.0066
     9 VCP           2.54  
    10 VPS29         5.29
```

Large DF with all of my data takes the form:

```
    Sample_ID      hugo_name     Expression     
    Sample_1       SNRPD3        6669.0
    Sample_1       ABCDEF        400.2
         ..
         ..
    Sample_2       RAB7A         1.75
    Sample_2       ZYXVU         9.4
```

I can subset my DF into just the genes on EHK_list:

```
            QC_geneSubset <- DF[DF$hugo_name %in% EHK_list,]

              sample_ID     hugo_name     expression
              1: Sample1      RAB7A         1382.78
              2: Sample1      C1orf43       11.78
              3: Sample1      CHMP2A        75.5
                   .
                   .
             11: Sample2      RAB7A         33.3
             12: Sample2      C1orf43       12.1
             13: Sample2      CHMP2A        1500
                   .
                   .
             21: Sample3      RAB7A         66
             22: Sample3      C1orf43       1
             23: Sample3      CHMP2A        19
                   .
                   .
```

but I can't figure out how to keep only rows from DF where both the DF "hugo_name" (i.e. gene name) matches that on the EHK_list AND the DF expression value is >=  the cutoff value from the EHK_minimum data frame. That is, I want to match the tuple (hugo_name, expression) and make sure that the sample has an expression value above the my listed cutoffs for >=9/10 genes on the list. Any ideas?

Comment: Using `dplyr` you could do `filter(df, hugo_name %in% EHK_list) %>% mutate(flag = ifelse(expression> threshold, "greater", "smaller"))`. That should get you close enough to where you want to be. You might need to join your data and your threshold values

Comment: Can you provide a small `dput` of your real data or QC_geneSubset?

Answer (score 1):

The `non-equi` join using `data.table` can be an appropriate option in this case as OP is willing to check for criteria where `expression` is more than `cutoff` expression defined in `EHK_minimum`.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(EHK_minimum)
setDT(DF)

DF[EHK_minimum, on=.(hugo_name, expression >= expression), nomatch=0]

#    sample_ID hugo_name expression
# 1:   Sample1   C1orf43     2.3697
# 2:   Sample2   C1orf43     2.3697
# 3:   Sample3    CHMP2A     3.4964
# 4:   Sample1    CHMP2A     3.4964
# 5:   Sample2    CHMP2A     3.4964
# 6:   Sample2     RAB7A     8.3988
# 7:   Sample3     RAB7A     8.3988
# 8:   Sample1     RAB7A     8.3988
```

**Data:** Created based on partial data provided by OP

```
EHK_list <- c("C1orf43", "CHMP2A", "GPI", "PSMB2", "PSMB4", 
           "RAB7A", "REEP5", "SNRPD3", "VCP", "VPS29")
EHK_minimum <- data_frame("hugo_name" = EHK_list, 
   "expression" = c(2.3697, 3.4964, 2.0620, 2.1240, 4.3081, 8.3988, 
                   1.4969, -0.0066, 2.5436, 5.2886))


DF <- read.table(text = 
"sample_ID     hugo_name     expression
1: Sample1      RAB7A         1382.78
2: Sample1      C1orf43       11.78
3: Sample1      CHMP2A        75.5
11: Sample2      RAB7A         33.3
12: Sample2      C1orf43       12.1
13: Sample2      CHMP2A        1500
21: Sample3      RAB7A         66
22: Sample3      C1orf43       1
23: Sample3      CHMP2A        19",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `data.table` solution is great. For the sake of it, there's one with `dplyr`.
Notice I changed to `threshold` the name of the variable in your key data.frame.

```
     EHK_list <- c("C1orf43", "CHMP2A",
                   "GPI", "PSMB2", "PSMB4", "RAB7A",
                   "REEP5", "SNRPD3", "VCP", "VPS29")

     EHK_minimum <- data_frame("hugo_name" = EHK_list,
                                  "threshold" = c(2.3697, 3.4964, 2.0620,
     2.1240, 4.3081, 8.3988,
     1.4969, -0.0066, 2.5436, 5.2886))
```

Given

```
    DF <- read.table(text = 
"sample_ID     hugo_name     expression
1: Sample1      RAB7A         1382.78
2: Sample1      C1orf43       11.78
3: Sample1      CHMP2A        75.5
11: Sample2      RAB7A         33.3
12: Sample2      C1orf43       12.1
13: Sample2      CHMP2A        1500
21: Sample3      RAB7A         66
22: Sample3      C1orf43       1
23: Sample3      CHMP2A        19",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

We join and filter

```
DF %>% left_join(EHK_minimum) %>% filter(expression >= threshold)
Joining, by = "hugo_name"
  sample_ID hugo_name expression threshold
1   Sample1     RAB7A    1382.78    8.3988
2   Sample1   C1orf43      11.78    2.3697
3   Sample1    CHMP2A      75.50    3.4964
4   Sample2     RAB7A      33.30    8.3988
5   Sample2   C1orf43      12.10    2.3697
6   Sample2    CHMP2A    1500.00    3.4964
7   Sample3     RAB7A      66.00    8.3988
8   Sample3    CHMP2A      19.00    3.4964
```

Comment: good answer. Couple of  minor comments. OP has mentioned condition as `expression value is >= the cutoff`. You can change your code to match same. Another point is perhaps you have not used data provided by OP as `threshold` column is mentioned as `expression` in data provided by OP. These changes make increase usability of your answer in future. Thanks.